Buck Average Modelling
I completed average modelling with Voreperian PWM switch model as described in Christophe Basso's book "Transfer Function of Switching Converters" and I compared the average model with measurement.
Below graph is the comparison result of Average Model Vs Measurement Result

I am getting good overlap of gain curve but I see there is large variation phase curve how ever switching frequency of the converter is 450 kHz. Converter is peak current mode based controller.
Can anyone provide any insight why there is a mismatch between measured phase and simulation phase?

Theoretical circuit vs implemented circuit is the probable reason.

@Andy aka...I have other circuit where it matches perfectly

That's good but it doesn't provide the necessary information to make an answer.
